# Efficient Aeson parsing for sum type toEncoding

Tags: json, parsing, haskell, aeson

I'm parsing a third party JSON structure into my own set of types. I'd like to parse in the most efficient way possible (I'm parsing data sent over a unix socket with Network.Socket)

Aeson's documentation claims that parsing with toEncoding yields up to a 3x speedup over toJSON, however I don't understand how to write a valid instance using toEncoding for my simple sum type.

for example:

```
data NodeLayout =
    SplitHorizontalLayout
    | SplitVerticalLayout
    | StackedLayout
    | TabbedLayout
    | DockAreaLayout
    | OutputLayout
    deriving (Eq, Generic)

instance ToJSON NodeLayout where
    toJSON = \case
        SplitHorizontalLayout -> "splith"
        SplitVerticalLayout   -> "splitv"
        StackedLayout         -> "stacked"
        TabbedLayout          -> "tabbed"
        DockAreaLayout        -> "dockarea"
        OutputLayout          -> "output"

instance FromJSON NodeLayout where
    parseJSON (String s) = pure $ case s of
        "splith"   -> SplitHorizontalLayout
        "splitv"   -> SplitVerticalLayout
        "stacked"  -> StackedLayout
        "tabbed"   -> TabbedLayout
        "dockarea" -> DockAreaLayout
        "output"   -> OutputLayout
        _          -> error "Received unrecognized NodeLayout"
    parseJSON _ = error "Error parsing NodeLayout"
```

I have other data types that will receive Vectors of this, but sometimes I receive a single value that needs to be parsed individually. How does one efficiently parse strings into sum types using toEncoding?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, Aeson does not provide an alternative to `fromJSON` for parsing / decoding.  The docs explain that `toEncoding` allows more efficient encoding / serialization - going from the Haskell in-memory representation to the wire format.  It's not clear from your question which direction you require to be fast.

You can provide an explicit `toEncoding` following the pattern of your `toJSON`.  [Data.Aeson.Encoding](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-1.4.2.0/docs/Data-Aeson-Encoding.html) provides a bunch of helper functions for writing these:

```hs
    toEncoding = \case
        SplitHorizontalLayout -> text "splith"
        SplitVerticalLayout   -> text "splitv"
        StackedLayout         -> text "stacked"
        TabbedLayout          -> text "tabbed"
        DockAreaLayout        -> text "dockarea"
        OutputLayout          -> text "output"
```

Comment: Both preferably

Comment: Is there a way to write the FromJSON instance in a way that would be more efficient?

Comment: You shouldn't need to use `.Internal` module, Public https://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-1.4.2.0/docs/Data-Aeson-Encoding.html is enough. If it's not, please open an issue, so we can discuss.

Comment: There are no way to write different (more efficient or not) `FromJSON` instances. There might be if there's luck with GSoC 2019. See https://summer.haskell.org/ideas.html#tokenstream-json-parsing

Comment: Thank you @phadej for your additional information. `text` is also exported from Data.Aeson.Encoding, so no problems there either.

Comment: Thanks @phadej, I updated the link above.  Glad to see the GSOC idea also.